# Unable to read logs message from IE console tab using selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, console, internet-explorer-11

I want to read console messages(info,warning and error) in IE 11 using selenium webdriver(C#). I tried alot with LogType.Browser but no success. Is there any possible way to fetch and read the console logs in IE using selenium? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you mean JavaScript console messages, such as those created with `console.log`, no, you cannot retrieve those using Selenium with IE. The IE driver implements the W3C WebDriver Specification, which does not support the Selenium logging API. Moreover, it’s unlikely that the driver will ever be able to retrieve those messages, as IE does not expose programmatic access to the browser developer console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim